# DRF - where to modify serializer response?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I need to encrypt/decrypt data that is being served from Django Rest Framework.

models.py

```
class Widget(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('MyAppUser', related_name='MyAppUser_owner')
    list = models.ForeignKey('WidgetList')
```

Depending on the user logged in the key would be different.

serializers.py

```
class WidgetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    list = serializers.CharField(source='list.name')

    class Meta:
        model=Widget
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'username', 'code', 'owner', 'list')
```

views.py

```
class WidgetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Widget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WidgetSerializer
    filter_class = WidgetFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        owner = self.request.user
        return super(WidgetList, self).get_queryset().filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

so depending on the user logged in (userkey is different per user) I need to run the following code -

GET

```
for object in queryset:
    object.code = decrypt_code(masterkey,
                                       userkey,
                                       object.code)
```

POST

```
object.code = encrypt_code(masterkey,
                                   userkey,
                                   object.code)
```

How do I integrate this code into a view without breaking the existing filter code or how would I integrate it into a serializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **decrypt** you can override `.validate_code()` method in the serializer.
To **encrypt** you can override `.to_representation()` method in the serializer.

More info you can learn [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior).

Comment: I got the .to_representation() to work.  Gotta say I'm less than impressed with the documentation.  FWIW I got the .to_representation to work with the decrypt just to get an understanding of it.

Answer (score 1):

Usig `pycryptodome` I managed to encrypt the data in the viewset and the decrypt I added into the `to_representation` method of the serializer.

Ex, supposing your data is using AES256 and you already have the decrypt and encrypt method. If your data is already encrypted from the same KEY you can use the decrypt method like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from myapp.aesencryption import AESCipher

class MyDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        """
        Get decrypted data.
        """
        aes = AESCipher( settings.SECRET_KEY[:16], 32)
        return {
            'id': obj.id,
             # dont need decrypt since it is an uuid.
            'value_id': obj.applicant_id.id,
            'value_name': aes.decrypt(obj.name),
            'value_type': aes.decrypt(obj.document_type),
            'value_code': aes.decrypt(obj.document_code)
        }

    class Meta:
        model = ApplicantPersonalData
        fields = ['id', 'value_id', 'value_name', 'value_type', 'value_code']
```

Data before the `to_representation` applied above:

```
    {
        "id": "8981c86c-a505-4c5f-b29e-623c82355f12",
        "value_id": "38061340-920f-4dcf-9c7b-daf506e13133",
        "value_name": "ezFCHryFi8MwUQxgW1iX5dHp7eLqImIegXBkaFRJiXdxZ4u8Rwn3RhFCbRaSYFbv",
        "value_type": "BQul2Yrt/Bl6Ixe+PAu+B+B9iMx3Lhx/uBdgwjjJDa//tnkRkb4hLDGS6+EByK7y",
        "value_code": "35ubHx9y9Xidzgq0JZEhqXJGqtrOE7y99sLc5HiajyOjb2g6Jj/bP6XslkM+cmJJ"
    },
```

Data after the application of the `to_representation` mentioned above:

```
    {
        "id": "8981c86c-a505-4c5f-b29e-623c82355f12",
        "value_id": "38061340-920f-4dcf-9c7b-daf506e13133",
        "value_name": "John Doe",
        "value_type": "passport",
        "value_code": "ABCD12345"
    },
```